# Retornar o comprimento da sequencia

Tags: php, array, split

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver:

Dada uma string `"aeiaaioooau"`, identificar sequencias existentes e contar seus elementos com PHP.

Uma sequencia seria `a`,`e`,`i`,`o` e `u` ...

> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> $s = "aeiaaioooau"
> ```
>
> - `"aei"` **é sequencia** de 3 elementos, portanto **soma + 3**
> - depois `"aa"` **não é sequencia**,portanto não soma nada
> - depois `"iooo"` **é sequência** de 4 elementos, portanto **soma + 4**
> - o proximo `"a"` **não soma** nada por não ser sequencia
> - por fim `"u"` **é sequencia** de 1 elemento, **soma + 1**
>
> Sendo os elementos sequenciais `"aei+iooo+u" = 8` elementos.

Como fazer isso com PHP?

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Olá. Não entendi muito bem a proposição. Por que "aai" não é sequência mas "iooo" é?

Comment: Qual a lógica? Por que o último *a* não é considerado uma sequência, mas *u*, sim? No caso de outra palavra, exemplo: *abecedario*, o resultado deverá ser *4* ou outro valor?

Comment: Isso é um exercício de escola? Você precisa, antes de aplicar essas lógicas, quebrar a string para ter os elementos distintos em um array para depois tentar utilizá-lo para cada situação. Boa sorte.

Comment: a lógica é que uma sequencia é sempre 'a,e,i,o , u' , portanto aaaeiiiiioooou é uma sequencia tanto como aeiou, mas aaaaeiaaaaaou , tem que ignorar essa cadeia de aaaaa para poder ser contabilizados.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
$s = "aeiaaioooau";
$sequences = array("aeiou", "aeio", "aei", "ae", "a", "eiou", "eio", "ei", "e", "iou", "io", "i", "o", "u");
$sequenceLengths = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= strlen($s); $j++) {
        $substring = substr($s, $i, $j - $i);
        if (in_array($substring, $sequences)) {
            $sequenceLengths[] = strlen($substring);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

$totalElements = array_sum($sequenceLengths);
echo "Total de elementos sequenciais: " . $totalElements;
?>
```

Neste exemplo, você define um array $sequences com todas as possíveis sequências possíveis ("aeiou", "aeio", "aei", etc.). Em seguida, você percorre a string e verifica todas as substrings possíveis para ver se elas estão presentes nas sequências definidas. Se estiverem, o comprimento da substring é adicionado ao array $sequenceLengths.

Por fim, você calcula a soma de todos os comprimentos das sequências encontradas e exibe o resultado. No caso do exemplo "aeiaaioooau", o resultado será 8 (como no exemplo).